# Hibernate error when using SELECT CASE WHEN

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to run this **Named** query to return 1 if it finds any record that meets WHERE condition:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS
(SELECT p
    FROM Books p
    WHERE bookNum = :bookNum
        AND author = :author
        AND bookID <> :bookID)
THEN 1
ELSE NULL
END
```

I used EXISTS to make it faster but I get this error on **TOMCAT SERVER START**.

> org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected end of subtree
>   [SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT p FROM com.userclasses.Books p WHERE
>   bookNum = :bookNum AND author = :author AND bookID <> :bookID) THEN 1
>   ELSE NULL END ]   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:54)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:47)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:82)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:261)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:185)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:124)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.checkNamedQueries(SessionFactoryImpl.java:549)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:413)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1872)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:906)

I ran the below code to get hibernate version, as it says in [this link](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-467) that it was fixed:

```
System.out.println(org.hibernate.Version.getVersionString());
System.out.println("Hibernate Version: "+ org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version.VERSION);
```

It tell me this in console

```
3.6.4.Final
Hibernate Version: 3.2.0.Final
```

Comment: I think the problem is with your inner query. Have you check whether the parameters passed are getting values.

Comment: The issue is, it is on server start, not on using the query on in during execution :( Can you please tell, if I use this SELECT COUNT(*) instead of EXISTS for doing same thing, will it be as fast as it ?

Comment: I do think that, it is problem with my hibernate as I changed query to SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT p FROM Books p) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END.....and still get error :) I think I should change my query to not use EXISTS :)

Comment: i think EXISTS will be more faster. And what you mean by the query SELECT p FROM Books p.

Comment: The query will return records from the table Book. I have to write a query to return 1 if there is ANY record in table Book that matches WHERE clause condition, otherwise return NULL (or may be 0). So, I wrote this query

Comment: have you tried with '!:' instead of '<>' for not equal in your inner query.

Comment: Making it SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT p FROM Books p) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END gave same error. I am sure now, it has to do with Hibernate version or something :( I will change it to COUNT(*) or put EXISTS in WHERE CLAUSE

Comment: You could try `Select 1 FROM Books p WHERE ...`, but it's database-specific, some dbs could not have "ability"

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS
(SELECT p
    FROM Books p
    WHERE bookNum = :bookNum
    AND author = :author
    AND bookID <> :bookID)
THEN 1
ELSE NULL
END FROM Books p
```

But adding FROM Books p will not be performance efficient as it will return list now, not a single record :(